# No se añade nada al hacer array_push() a mi variable

Tags: php, array

Actualmente tengo un `$info_products` que contiene un número X de arrays (se genera previamente este objeto) por tanto `$info_products` quedaría así:

```
$info_products[    
    {
    "id_product": "364",
    "price": "1.5600",
    "quantity": "1.0000",
    "total_weight": "0.3000",
    "reference": "36107"
    },
    {
    "id_product": "453",
    "price": "2.5900",
    "quantity": "1.0000",
    "total_weight": "0.8000",
    "reference": "56466"
    }
]
```

A su vez, tengo una tabla de llamada `attributes` de este estilo:

```
attribute_id | entity_id | value |
----------------------------------
    154      |     364   |  Ok   |
```

De la que tengo que extraer el valor de un atributo. Por tanto tengo que recorrer los array de `$info_products` y realizar un `SELECT`.

```
foreach($info_products as $info => $datos ){
  $select = $conn->select()
                 ->from(array($coreResource->getTableName('attributes')),
                        array('ref_att' => 'value')
                       )
                 ->where('attribute_id=154 AND entity_id='. $datos['id_product']);
  //154 es el id del atributo a sacar y entity_id es el id del producto
  $ref_product = $conn->fetchAll($select); 
  $ref = $ref_product[0]; 
  /*esto lo hago porque ref_product es un array así:
    ref_product[array(ref_att => value)] y solo quiero el array de 
    dentro*/
  array_push($info_products[$datos], $ref);
}
```

Aclaro, que un `id_product` de los array no tiene por qué tener atributo. 
Por ejemplo, el segundo array con `id_product 453` no tiene nada asociado en la tabla `attributes`.

Y finalmente añado el array `$ref` al array correspondiente, quedando algo así:

```
   {
   "id_product": "364",
   "price": "1.5600",
   "quantity": "1.0000",
   "total_weight": "0.3000",
   "reference": "36107",
   "ref_att": "ok"  //campo añadido
   }
```

Mi problema es que jamás me añade nada, el `SELECT` lo hace bien y cuando depuro puedo ver que guardo en `$ref` el array correspondiente o un `null`, pero el `array_push()` no añade nunca nada.

No llevo más que 1 semana por un proyecto en el trabajo con Magento y Zend, y es posible que me esté perdiendo en algún lado por el framework o estoy con algún fallo tonto.

Comment: No entiendo por qué el push se realiza a $info_products[$datos] ¿La key no es "info"? Además ¿Es $info_products["tuClave"] un array?

Comment: @Juliosor tiene razón, no debería ser `array_push($info_products[$info], $ref);` ? ya que  `$info` es el indice del array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un error cuando estas utilizando `array_push($info_products[$datos], $ref);` `$info_products[$datos]` no es un array, es más no debería existir.

Recuerda que la clave del array en el foreach en tu caso sería la variable `$info` por lo que deberías utilizar `$info_products[$info]`

Además, no estás metiendo correctamente la nueva clave en el array

```
"ref_att": "ok"  //campo añadido
```

Yo lo hubiera metido así

```
$info_product[$info]["ref_att"] = $ref;
```

Particularmente yo usaría un bucle `for $i` para ver más claros los índices del array